# How to get "key" from params?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
<%= params[:select] %>  # key=qwerty secret=qwerty token=qwerty token_secret=qwerty
```

Please tell me how I can get "key" ? I do not understand:

```
<%= params{[:select[:key]]} %> # {"tweet"=>"", "select"=>"key=qwerty secret=qwerty token=qwerty token_secret=qwerty", "controller"=>"twitter_postings", "action"=>"index"}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access to the select key and over its value to split the content, getting the first one you have "key":

```
params = {
  "tweet"=>"",
  "select"=>"key=qwerty secret=qwerty token=qwerty token_secret=qwerty",
  "controller"=>"twitter_postings",
  "action"=>"index"
}
p params['select'].split.first
# "key=qwerty"
```

You can also turn it into a hash if it's easier for you:

```
select_hash = params['select'].split.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) do |element, hash|
  key, value = element.split('=')
  hash[key] = value
end

p select_hash['key']
# "qwerty
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will helping you.

```
params = {
  "tweet"=>"",
  "select"=>"key=qwerty secret=qwerty token=qwerty token_secret=qwerty",
  "controller"=>"twitter_postings",
  "action"=>"index"
}
```

for getting key value (`qwerty`) from this params following query will helping you.

```
params["select"].split.first.split("=").second
# => "qwerty"
```

**steps: 1**

```
params["select"].split
# => ["key=qwerty", "secret=qwerty", "token=qwerty", "token_secret=qwerty"]
```

find the value and split them

**steps: 2**

```
params["select"].split.first.split("=")
# => ["key", "qwerty"]
```

pick first value and split again with `=`

**steps: 3**

```
params["select"].split.first.split("=").second
# => "qwerty"
```

finally pick the second value.